How do I set CurSearch from my vimrc?
patch-8.2.4724 added a new highlight group for the search match under the cursor, but it looks identical to the Search highlight group by default. I know I need to set it to a colour for it to make a difference.
I've tried various permutations of linking it to a different colour in my .vimrc and nothing works:
highlight default link CurSearch IncSearch

Using that same command in cmdline mode works fine. Editing my colorscheme and adding it there also works. How can I do it from my .vimrc?

Regarding your edits: :help cmdline.txt is titled "Command-line mode" and ~/.vim/vimrc is a file that will be used for initialization if no ~/.vimrc is present. Just trying to live up to my reputation as a terrible know-it-all :-)

Yup, understood! :D However since "command line" is also a common phrase for "in a terminal" (especially on Windows), I edited it to unambiguously refer to the vim mode by avoiding that overloaded phrase. I didn't know about vimrc!

The way suggested in :help colorscheme-override is to use and autocommand to set it right after your colorscheme, whenever your colorscheme changes.
This will also keep your colorscheme tweaks limited to one colorscheme.
augroup colorscheme_override
    autocmd!
    autocmd ColorScheme sandydune highlight link CurSearch IncSearch
augroup END
colorscheme sandydune


Highlight groups are wiped when a colorscheme is loaded, so add it right after your colorscheme:
colorscheme sandydune
highlight link CurSearch IncSearch

